# Explanation of cooling and dehumidifcation process on psychometric chart

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, humidity

I've got the same problem while trying to understand air cooling and heating.

My textbook shows a picture like the following:

[image: Mollier chart for air cooling]

In this Mollier chart we s that for air cooling we have too cool down the temperature, then dehumidificate it and finally heat it up. Why are these 3 phases necessary?

More specifically: I don't see the reason for cool down and then heat up.
But I have a very basic knowledge of this topic.

Same problem for the winter process: first we heat up, then we humidificate until 100% and finally we continue to heat up. Why do we have to do it in three steps?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases (heating air in the winter and cooling it in the summer), you want to send outlet air into a home or structure that does NOT contain 100% relative humidity.  This would tend to cause condensation inside the home or structure, and steady influxes of moisture in this situation is a bad thing, as it leads to mold, mildew, wood rot, etc.

Comment: Ok, but why in the step 1 do we need to reach 100% of relative humidity?

Comment: @user168141, reaching 100% relative humidity is a consequence of cooling the 80% relative humidity air.  As the temperature goes down, the relative humidity goes up, and reaches 100% at a temperature of 74 deg. F on your chart.  At that point, water condenses out of the cooling air and relative humidity stays at 100%.  This means that your goal is not to reach 100% relative humidity, your goal is to cool the air down, but relative humidity is affected as a result.  For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity

Comment: Sure, but my question is: wouldn't it be easier a path like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxvB.jpg) (the green one)? Or it is not feasible for some reason? Which reason?

Comment: Or maybe [this other path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkAA6.jpg)

Comment: If you want to install extra equipment (a dehumidifier), your preferred path can be taken.  Question: how much energy would it take to regenerate the material that does the dehumidification?  To lower humidity at a constant temperature requires something that absorbs water, and this absorbent would have to be heated to drive water out of it, after it becomes saturated.  Thus, you should choose a dehumidification path that minimizes the sum of equipment and operating costs, and is also practical.